# CreateFile not returning a proper Handle - devices in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-2010, device-driver

Hoping to find somebody that has experience with services in windows.

I am trying to use the `NdisProt` driver for ethernet adapters in Delphi

```
my_Handle := CreateFile(PChar('\\.\NdisProt'),
    GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_READ, 0, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

(have tried with `\\.\\NdisProt` too)

After execution `my_Handle` **always** has the value '4008' decimal and GetLastError always returns `0`

If I try to read or write to the file I get acces violation, anybody knows why I'm getting this unwanted behavior?

Comment: It's used for accessing devices directly - not like normal file in a file system. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Did you try a google search? I know device drivers can be really hard to connect to (I have done similar things with CD-ROM drives); and searches like this helped me big time: http://www.google.com/search?q=createfile+\\.\NdisProt  (It might be just a permission or naming isssue).

Answer (score 8):

If `CreateFile` doesn't return `Invalid_Handle_Value`, then it has given you a valid handle, or else the driver for that device is severely buggy. Assume the former.

An access violation has nothing to do with your handle value. It means you're accessing memory that doesn't belong to your process (such as by dereferencing a null pointer, an uninitialized pointer, a non-pointer, or an already freed pointer). Your problem lies elsewhere, perhaps in the reading or writing code that you neglected to show here.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question is not an assignment statement. It's a comparison expression. You should have gotten a warning from the compiler that the variable's value is undefined. If it always has the value 4008 after executing that code, then you should check whether it also had that value *before* executing that code. It could simply be that `CreateFile` is returning a valid handle value, but you're not using the value it returns.

If 4008 isn't the value `CreateFile` returns, then it's probable that 4008 isn't a valid handle value. If the OS treats handles as pointers (or if it performs some kind of transform on handles to generate pointers), then it could be that the pointer corresponding to that "handle" is not a valid address in your process; that would explain the access violation.

Comment: Thank you for the new answer Rob, I forgot to put the semicolon in the question above, so yes It was an assignment.(updated now) I debugged the value of my_Handle before Createfile, the result was 0. Also, I noticed that running the compiler without debugger support from the IDE the value of the handle is always 4000. I have the original source in C# and I'm trying to make it native. In the original code the handle always gets a value between 250 and 300 (at least on my pc) Original code: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sendrawpacket.aspx

Comment: @Ed.C: The handle value is largely irrelevant; what matters is what the handle refers to. If you keep getting the same value, that's probably just an indication that the Delphi RTL is being consistant in *it's* allocation of handles; the variability under .NET would seem to indicate some kind of non-determinism or something like that...